# Minipage top alignment in multicol environment

Tags: minipage, multicol

I have the following lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[]{foo.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Right now my `minipage` is at the bottom of the second page but I want to have it at the top of the second page but neither the `t` nor the `!t` argument get me there.
I want to have its position fixed there so when I may change the text on the prior site its alignment on the second site won't be altered.

Comment: `minipage` is not a float, it more or less works as a miniature of a page with the specified width. The `[t]` tells TeX how to align it with the surroundings. It looks like you want `figure` instead.

Comment: I have already looked into `figure` but it doesnt work in multicol environments

Comment: You are right, floats cannot be used inside `multicols`.